# How to get the Image of dynamic picturebox in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

This is how I open a multiple pictures and set to flowLyaoutPanel

```
DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                // Create a PictureBox.
                try
                {
                    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                    Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);
                    pb.Height = loadedImage.Height;
                    pb.Width = loadedImage.Width;
                    pb.Image = loadedImage;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                        "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                        "Details (send to Support):\n\n" + ex.StackTrace
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                        + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                        "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is where Im stuck, I need to get the Image in every picturebox by use of looping

```
foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) {
            if (ctrl is PictureBox) {

                //problem goes here
                Image img = (PictureBox)ctrl.Image;

                byte[] arr;
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to cast the control to picturebox?

Comment: `Image img = ((PictureBox)ctrl).Image;`

Comment: Oh! im just missing some parenthesis. Got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OfType<T>` to filter a collection down by the type.

```
using System.Linq;
...
foreach (PictureBox pictureBox in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    Image img = pictureBox.Image;

    byte[] arr;
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));        
}
```